# Mobile window.ondevicemotion triggering even if device is not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using `window.ondevicemotion` to detect the `tilt` action for mobile device , anyway , I have put my device on a flat desk , made sure it is not moving at all , my function was simply to alert a string , and the alert dialog kept popping even the device was not moving at all , any idea why is this happening ?

Edit:

to clarify my question , How can i detect motion only if device is really moved ( tilted , shaked ... etc ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case someone is looking for answer for this question , i didnt know about alpha , beta , and  gamma , before I ask this question , more info can be found here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {
  var absolute = event.absolute;
  var alpha    = event.alpha;
  var beta     = event.beta;
  var gamma    = event.gamma;

  // Do stuff with the new orientation data
}
```

it is wierd but the actual device motion can be detected through orientation event !

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the case that the device is nearly always firing `ondevicemotion` events, even though it is imperceptible to the naked eye.

You might want to try only showing the alert if a certain threshold of acceleration or pitch is reached.

Comment: is this an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 0):

ondevicemotion will fire continiously, similar to onScroll.  When an alert is done, subsequent alerts will queue and will continue to show.

Comment: what do you mean ? alert action is causing this ?